# Search within single document using Elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

If I want to search an index I can use:

```
$curl -XGET 'X/index1/_search?q=title:ES'
```

If I want to search a document type I can use:

```
$curl -XGET 'X/index1/docType1/_search?q=title:ES'
```

But if I want to search a specific document, this doesn't work:

```
$curl -XGET 'X/index1/docType1/documentID/_search?q=title:ES'
```

Is there a simple work around for this so that I can search within a single document as opposed to an entire index or an entire document type? To explain why I need this, I have to do some resource intensive queries to find what I'm looking for. Once I find the documents I need, I don't actually need the whole document, just the highlighted portion that matches the query. But I don't want to store all the highlighted hits in memory because I might not need them for a few hours and at times they could take up a lot of space (I would also prefer not to write them to disk). I'd rather store a list of document ids so that when I need the highlighted portion of a document I can just run the highlighted query on a *specific document* and get back the highlighted portion. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can index the document's id as a field, then when you query, include the unique document id as a term to narrow the results just to that single document.

```
'$curl -XPOST 'X/index1/docType1/_search' -d '{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
              "must":[
                  {"match":{"doc":"223"}},
                  {"match":{"title":"highlight me please"}}
               ]
        }
   }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Ids Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html) in Elasticsearch to search on a single document. Elasticsearch by default, indexes a field called *[_uid](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html)* which is the combination of *type* and *id* so that it can be used for queries, aggregations, scripts, and sorting.

So the query you need will be as follows

```
curl -XGET 'X/index1/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "ES"
          }
        },
        {
          "ids": {
            "type" : "docType1",
            "values": [
              "documentID"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

If you need to search on multiple documents, then specify doc_ids in the values array in ids query.